# TypeError: 'Query' object is not iterable in Odoo 10

Tags: python

can anyone help me with this error as I don't find any mistake in this code line (**if soline.adv_issue_ids and not soline.issue_product_ids:**)?

What I'm trying to do is the following:

**In the IF condition, I'm trying to get the value of the many2many (adv_issue_ids) and one2many (issue_product_ids) fields from the object sale.order.line.**

Details of variable used in the code line:

**soline** is a sale order line recordset (ex: sale.order.line(129))

**adv_issue_ids** is a many2many field in sale.order.line

**issue_product_ids** is a one2many field in sale.order.line

Please find the error log below

```
File "/workspace/parts/my_module/wizard/sale_line.py", line 76, in function_name
**if soline.adv_issue_ids and not soline.issue_product_ids:**
File "/workspace/parts/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 931, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/workspace/parts/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1035, in determine_value
record._prefetch_field(self)
File "/workspace/parts/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3087, in _prefetch_field
result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
File "/workspace/parts/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3027, in read
self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
File "/workspace/parts/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3117, in _read_from_database
self._apply_ir_rules(query, 'read')
File "/workspace/parts/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4131, in _apply_ir_rules
where_clause, where_params, tables = Rule.domain_get(self._name, mode)
**TypeError: 'Query' object is not iterable**
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Query object is not iterable, hence use all() function to fetch all values.

Try `query.all()`

Comment: Hi Gauri Shankar, thanks for your quick response. Actaully the "soline" is a sale order line recordset (ex: sale.order.line(129)) and we should be able to get value of any fields of that object sale.order.line. But this error looks very strange. Thanks once again.

Comment: I just tried soline.all() and I'm getting the following error ---AttributeError: 'sale.order.line' object has no attribute 'all'. Please let me know if you need more information on this error, so you will be able to help me. Thanks!

Comment: @Praveen could you please share the module which has this  `if` checks.

Comment: Hi Gauri, sharing the whole module is bit difficult, but I can share the method where I'm getting this error from. Hope this will give you some idea. Thanks! <br/>@api.multi <br/>def function_name(self, orderlines=[]): <br/>sol_obj = self.env['sale.order.line'] <br/>olines = sol_obj.browse(orderlines) <br/>lines = []<br/> for soline in olines:<br/> if soline.adv_issue_ids and not soline.issue_product_ids:<br/> raise UserError(_ ('The Order Line is in error. Please correct!'))

Comment: I'm not able to understand your code but I'll try. Before your code hits the `if` clause, can you print out the type and value of `soline.adv_issue_ids` and `not soline.issue_product_ids` and share here?

Comment: Hi @Gauri, please find the values and types.                                                 
Value of soline.issue_product_ids:  **sale.order.line.issues.products(17, 18)**
Type of soline.issue_product_ids:  **<class 'odoo.api.sale.order.line.issues.products'>**
Value of soline.adv_issue_ids:  **sale.advertising.issue()**
Type of soline.adv_issue_ids:  **<class 'odoo.api.sale.advertising.issue'>**
Value of soline:  **sale.order.line(129,)**
Type of soline:  **<class 'odoo.api.sale.order.line'>**

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Been busy. Have you fixed the issue yet?

Comment: Hi @Gauri, no, not yet. Solution for this issue could be simple, but not yet figured out, thanks!